# Getting selectedvalues of jlists

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listselectionlistener

```
for(Object a : freelist.getSelectedValues()){

        }
```

freelist is a JList; how abouts would I get selected values of the other JLists, while not making the method over again (2 times)?

Comment: The best approach is to write separate methods for the other JLists.

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about a.m. issue

Comment: I've basically 3 Jlists. I want to get the selectedvalues for all of them, how do I do that without using 3 different methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method with a list as parameter and a callback object for example.

Below is a **possibly over-engineered** example, but it may give you a clearer idea.

```
interface ListItemCallback {
    void doWithListItem(Object listItem);
}

public void iterateOverSelectedListValues(JList list, ListItemCallback callback) {
     for (Object o : list.getSelectedValues()) {
               callback.doWithListItem(o);
     }
}

// calling the code
iterateOverSelectedListValues(myJList, new ListItemCallback() {
            public void doWithListItem(Object o) {
                      // very useful processing here...
            }
});
```